# Create an object with an inherited object as a parameter

Tags: c#, inheritance, radix

I have a problem concerning inheritance and constructor in C#.

Indeed, I created a class Elements and classes which inherits from it, like Window or Message.

At some point, I wanted another class to use, in its constructor, a List of Elements so that it can use both Windows and Messages. However, when I create my new object, it requires only the base type, Elements.

I thus can not create something like :

```
obj = new Obj(List<Window> w)
```

It just allows

```
obj = new Obj(List<Elements> e)
```

I really don't know what it the problem. I tried to set the Elements class as abstract because I will never need to create an object "Element", but it still doesn't work.

If someone could help it would be really nice :)
Thanks !

Comment: Please show a complete set of class definitions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>` is not covariant, so if your constructor expects `List<BaseClass>` you cannot pass `List<DerivedClass>`.

Use `IEnumerable<BaseClass>` instead, to get covariance.

Or make your class generic, with generic constraint:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : Element
{
    public MyClass(List<T> items)
    {

    }
}
```